# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] after rename the file

Tags: python, pandas

I've extract the file, rename it, and save in a create folder with the current date as the folder name. 
however, when I try to read the csv file, it say it there's no file.

I've run the code where extract, rename and save the file which works fine, and there is a file in the folder. However, when I try to run the file, it say the file is not there.

Below is my code:

```
os.chdir('/Users/John/Downloads')
curdir = os.path.dirname('/Users/John/Desktop/Test/')
timedir = time.strftime('%y-%m-%d')
savepath = os.path.join(curdir + '/' , timedir)
try:
    os.makedirs(savepath)
except:
    pass
with ZipFile ('myraw.zip', 'r') as zipfile:
     zipfile.extractall(path='test')
     os.rename('/Users/John/Downloads/Test1/Dominos.csv', savepath + "/my_1.csv")
```

read the csv file

```
filep = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/John/Desktop/Test/my_1.csv')
```

Comment: Your `savepath` doesn't match where you're reading from - there should be a time directory that the `.csv` is inside of. Are you sure the file is where it should be for the path you're reading?

Comment: @Oliver.R it should, because when I run the code for os.rename it appears the extracted file is there in the folder.

Comment: @Oliver.R hi oliver, any suggestion on this or where I did a mistake? appreciate if you could highlight

Comment: As far as I'm convinced (and as stated above), if your code is exactly as above, then I believe your read is reading from the wrong file place. In fact, your paths are all messed up. You `chdir()` to `/Downloads`, then `extractall()` to `/Downloads/test`, before renaming something from `/Downloads/Test1` (a different directory to your extract folder) to your savepath `/Desktop/Test/2020-03-10` (as you append the `timedir` to `curdir` and save to `savepath`), before finally trying to read directly from `/Desktop/Test`. I don't see how this would work if unless you had heaps of files everywhere.